# I want to know about printing NFC tag time out

Tags: pi-3, c++, c, nfc

I used libnfc and nfc-poll command.
I get a UID and something else

can I get a information about NFC tag time and print it out?

Comment: There's no timer on a RFID tag. You have to note the time first seen, time last seen and do whatever timeout in your code.

Comment: I have been using PN532 NFC Reader. I have no idea How I record it